# Android Studio Dependancies: I want to use and edit a library

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

I can't seem to find any solid information on this.

I have an external library that I want to use (OSMDroid). I have it imported by adding it to my build.grade file. Its all fine and it works well enough.

However, I have an issue with certain image resources not displaying when I try and change them. The location icon for instance, on the map, I have changed to a custom icon and this custom icon displays on the numerous virtual devices I have created but not on any real device, it always defaults back to the icon that exists in the library.

For this reason I would like to use the library locally. That is import it as I would a python module, allowing me to edit aspects like the default icons directly.

I've tried a couple of the methods for importing libraries but they are either really old and not applicable or they just don't work.

Comment: Please explain in detail what you tried and what specific problems you encountered.

Comment: I added the unzipped source from github and added the library as a module (as described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-android-studio)
That came back with an error related to pom.xml

Comment: Android doesn't (typically) use pom.xml files

Comment: Yeah, I understand that the pom.xml is a product of Gradle?
Gradle sync failed: Cannot get property 'pom' on extra properties extension as it does not exist is the Gradle error I get.

Comment: For a Maven build, `pom.xml` is input. For a Gradle build, `pom.xml` is output. I don't know why they have a `pom.xml` file in [the `osmdroid-android` module source code](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/tree/master/osmdroid-android). Your problem is not generally with Android Studio, though, so much as it is with the specific combination of OSMDroid and Android Studio. You might review [their docs on this](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-build-osmdroid-from-source), and then ask for OSMDroid support if you encounter continued issues.